# Silence 'info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.'

Tags: yarnpkg

When running `yarn check`, I see:

```
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.                                                                                                                                        
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
```

[This GitHub comment](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo/issues/473#issuecomment-375267378) says that the message can be safely ignored.

Is there a way to prevent it from occurring in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about `yarn check` but for installing/updating: `yarn --silent` or even better `yarn --silent --ignore-optional`

`yarn --silent` installs optional deps, but without the output.

Note: If running with `--ignore-optional` flag you may be dependent on some of the optional dependencies without realising it. So I recommend deleting your `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` file and then running `yarn --ignore-optional` before testing your project. If it turns out there were optional deps you required, then add them as [dev] deps [accordingly].
Although if it was just `fsevents` and that was never being installed, no worries.

Answer (score 3):

Currently it does not seem possible to prevent messages about optional dependencies which are not explicitly required.

See the following `yarn` GitHub issues:

- [[FR] a way to ignore packages #4611](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4611)
- [Add flag to ignore individual optional packages #5251](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5251)

Comment: Is it possible to remove the optional dependency completely?